# Парсинг json по ссылке с Bitfinex unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужна ваша помощь. Мне необходимо передать в unity 2d массив доступный по ссылке: https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1h:tETCUSD/hist?limit=160

Формат: [[.,.,...],[.,.,...],[.,.,...]...]

На питоне подобное реализуется в 2 строчки:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:15m:tETCUSD..) 
response = json.loads(response.text)
mas[0]=response[i][1] 
mas[1]=response[i][2]
```

но мне необходима реализация на C#. Все чего я добился это получать стринг по ссылке приведенной выше таким образом:

```
IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(GetThisUrl);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
```

это код с оф сайта юнити и далее я не продвинулся ни на шаг. Очень не хочется писать парсер для такой вроде тупой задачи. Помогите превратить эти данные в string[][].

Или скажите чего почитать если это и в правду сложная задача.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html

Comment: Чтото я совсем тупой( Если тебе не составит труда написать скрипт был бы очень признателен, а то третий час какуюто херабору делаю.